# Providing access to EFS from ECS task

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

I am struggling to get an ECS task to be able to see an EFS volume.
The terraform config is:

**EFS DEFINITION**

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "persistent" {
encrypted = true
}

resource "aws_efs_access_point" "access" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "mount" {
  for_each = {for net in aws_subnet.private : net.id => {id = net.id}}
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.efs.id]
}
```

---

**TASK DEFINITION**

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app" {
  family                   = "backend-app-task"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.fargate_cpu
  memory                   = var.fargate_memory
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.backendapp.rendered
  volume {
    name = "persistent"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
      root_directory          = "/opt/data"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      transit_encryption_port = 2999
      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.access.id
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**SECURITY GROUP**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "efs" {
  name        = "efs-security-group"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    protocol        = "tcp"
    from_port       = 2999
    to_port         = 2999
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.ecs_tasks.id]
    cidr_blocks = [for net in aws_subnet.private : net.cidr_block]
  }
}
```

---

**TASK ROLE**

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_role" {
  name               = "ecsTaskRole"

  assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_execution_role_base.json
  managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticFileSystemFullAccess","arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy", aws_iam_policy.ecs_exec_policy.arn]
}
```

As I understand the AWS docs, the IAM role should have access, and the security group should be passing traffic, but the error suggests that the task cannot resolve the EFS instance.

The error message is:

```
ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: Failed to resolve "fs-0000000000000.efs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct.
```

I've manually confirmed in the console that the EFS id is correct, so I can only conclude that it cannot resolve due to a network/permissions issue.

-- EDIT --
**ECS SERVICE DEFINITION**

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "main" {
  name            = "backendservice"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn
  desired_count   = var.app_count
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  enable_execute_command = true

  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.ecs_tasks.id]
    subnets          = aws_subnet.private.*.id
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app.id
    container_name   = "server"
    container_port   = var.app_port
  }

  depends_on = [aws_alb_listener.backend]
}
```

**ECS TASK SECURITY GROUP**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ecs_tasks" {
  name        = "backend-ecs-tasks-security-group"
  description = "allow inbound access from the ALB only"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    protocol        = "tcp"
    from_port       = var.app_port
    to_port         = var.app_port
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb.id]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

**VPC DEFINITION (minus internet gateway)**

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "172.17.0.0/16"
}

# Create var.az_count private subnets, each in a different AZ
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count             = var.az_count
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, count.index)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count                   = var.az_count
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, var.az_count + count.index)
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}
```

---

### EDIT

It turned out the mountPoints block was missing from the container template. I have now added it, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the error message?

Comment: Are the EFS mount targets in the same subnets as the ECS Fargate tasks? Also you need to make sure "Enable DNS Support" is enabled in the VPC.

Comment: Enable dns support is not explicitly on, but apparently it defaults to true. Yes, they're in the same subnet

Comment: You really shouldn't be getting that error then. I suggest spinning up a small EC2 instance in the same subnet to debug that.

Comment: @MarkB I've added the ecs service definition, just in case I've done something stupid (I'm new to this)

Comment: Are you allowing all outbound traffic in the ECS task's security group?

Comment: I think. so, yes, I've added the security group definition

Comment: I really don't see any difference in your code, and some Terraform code I have that works. The only difference I see is you are using a non-standard EFS port `2999` instead of the standard `2049`. I don't see how that would result in the specific error you are seeing. I will say however though that I have found bugs in Fargate's EFS support when trying to use any port other than `2049`. It was never reliable for me until I just used `2049`

Comment: I've just tried 2049 and it was the same. Does the IAM role look ok?

Comment: Actually no, the IAM role should be `AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess`. The one you are using gives permission to create/delete filesystems, but it doesn't give permission to mount those filesystems. You need one of the `AmazonElasticFileSystemClient*` roles to be able to mount the file system and access the contents.

Comment: I've just given that a go - no difference. I'm stumped. Thank you for your help, anway!

Comment: @Alex can you add the code for subnets as well?

Comment: @MarkoE Sure, done!

Comment: One additional question: is there anything in the ECR image that would require IAM permissions to be set? Usually there is a task role and a service role in ECS, so might be something related to that as well.

Comment: I don't think so, it connects to an rds instance, but that's all. It was all working fine until I tried to add the EFS volume. Oh, and it pulls some SSM parameters, but again, working fine until I added the volume

Comment: @Alex I don't see there is an attribute with the name `cidr_block` exported for `aws_subnet` resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/subnet#attributes-reference. You might need to check that. Unless I'm missing something based on the docs. :)

Comment: I'm talking about this: `cidr_blocks = [for net in aws_subnet.private : net.cidr_block]`. Also, `cidr_blocks` is optional. So I would try omitting it first to see if if works, then specify the CIDR blocks explicitly, and then try to find a way to provide those values using Terraform. Although, I didn't find even a data source that has `cidr_block` as an attribute.

Comment: @MarkoE Ok, I tried removing it, but the output is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242545/discussion-between-alex-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 2):

Run into this problem, this is what I did to resolve:

1. `platform_version = "1.4.0"` on the `aws_ecs_service`, its possible its no longer relevant but was in this blog post I used as a starting point https://medium.com/@ilia.lazebnik/attaching-an-efs-file-system-to-an-ecs-task-7bd15b76a6ef
2. Made sure `aws_efs_mount_target` has `subnet_id` and `security_groups` set to same ones used by the service. Since I use multiple subnets for multiple availability zones I created mount target for each of them.
3. Added standard EFS port 2049 to `ingress` as without that mount operation was failing with timeout error.