# EFS volume hangs when accessed from an ECS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

I was previously having issues providing access to EFS from an ECS task ([Providing access to EFS from ECS task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309915/providing-access-to-efs-from-ecs-task))
This has now been resolved, inasmuch as the task starts, and it all looks fine.

The problem is that running `df`, or `ls` or `touch` on the mountpoint hangs indefinitely.

The task definition is below:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:000000000000:task-definition/backend-app-task:53",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "server",
            "image": "000000000000.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/foo-backend:latest-server",
            "cpu": 512,
            "memory": 1024,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "persistent",
                    "containerPath": "/opt/data/",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/foo",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "backend-app-task",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/ecsTaskRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/myEcsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 53,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "persistent",
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "fileSystemId": "fs-00000000000000000",
                "rootDirectory": "/",
                "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
                "transitEncryptionPort": 2049,
                "authorizationConfig": {
                    "accessPointId": "fsap-00000000000000000",
                    "iam": "ENABLED"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.efsAuth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.efs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.25"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "512",
    "memory": "1024",
    "registeredAt": "2022-03-08T14:23:47.391Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root",
    "tags": []
}
```

According to the docs, hanging can occur when large amounts of data are being written to the EFS volume. This is not the case here, the EFS volume is new, and empty, with a size of 6KiB. I also tried configuring it with provisioned throughput, but that did not make any difference.

---

EDIT

IAM role definition:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_execution_role_base" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

# ECS task execution role
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name               = var.ecs_task_execution_role_name
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_execution_role_base.json
}

# ECS task execution role policy attachment
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_task_execution_role2" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess"
}



resource "aws_iam_policy" "ecs_exec_policy" {
  name = "ecs_exec_policy"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action   = ["ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                    "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                    "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                    "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel",
                    ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_role" {
  name               = "ecsTaskRole"

  assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_execution_role_base.json
  managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess","arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy", aws_iam_policy.ecs_exec_policy.arn]
}
```

Comment: So the FS is mounted to `/opt/data` but it's unusable?

Comment: Is this deployed to Fargate or EC2?

Comment: Yes, /opt/data, and unusable. It is deployed to Fargate

Comment: @Alex Maybe the authorization config is tripping it up?

Comment: Also: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition#:~:text=This%20argument%20is%20ignored%20when%20using%20authorization_config.

Comment: @MarkoE Probably, I've added the definition of the task execution role, and the task role, both of which should have AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but can you try it with `"transitEncryptionPort": 2049,` completely removed from the task definition? This is what I had to do in order to get rid of seemingly random EFS connection hanging.

Comment: @MarkB Err... That fixed it... I can't decide if I feel stupid or not. Thank you so much, I've been trying to debug this for  days!

Comment: @Alex it's a bug in the EFS support in Fargate. I don't know exactly what is happening, I just know if you specify a port there you get these random network lockups.